# TooManyMethodsFoundException on a suppress with Bundle.class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking

When trying to run tests with mock objects, I got the following error:

```
    org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.TooManyMethodsFoundException: Several matching methods found, please specify the argument parameter types so that PowerMock can determine which method you're referring to.
Matching methods in class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity were:
void onCreate( android.os.Bundle.class )
void onCreate( android.os.Bundle.class android.os.PersistableBundle.class )
void onCreate( android.os.Bundle.class )
void onCreate( android.os.Bundle.class )
void onCreate( android.os.Bundle.class )

at nl.han.alfam.presentation.CarDetailsActivityTest.setUp(CarDetailsActivityTest.java:47)
```

Line 47:

```
suppress(method(AppCompatActivity.class, "onCreate", Bundle.class));
```

There are apparently multiple methods that support a Bundle.class parameter. I've tried without Bundle.class too, but that didn't help at all.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue with PowerMockito and `Fragment`'s `onCreate`. This is working for me.

Instead of:

```
PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.method(Fragment.class, "onCreate", Bundle.class));
```

Use:

```
PowerMockito.suppress(Fragment.class.getMethod("onCreate", Bundle.class));
```

Comment: In my case it was the same working solution with PowerMockito.stub

Comment: works perfect! you safe my f**** day! and the tests lol!! thanks !